# Which types of updates will I continue to get in 12.04 LTS?

Tags: updates

I've decided to keep using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Besides the updates from the manually added PPA's, which other updates will I get?

In particular, I'm curious about:

- Security updates
- Kernel updates
- Software (such as Rhythmbox, Chromium, Firefox, etc) updates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [StableReleaseUpdates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) page.

> Stable release updates will, in general, only be issued in order to
>   fix **high-impact bugs**. Examples of such bugs include:
>
> - Bugs which may, under realistic circumstances, directly cause a **security vulnerability**. These are done by the security team and are
>     documented at [SecurityTeam/UpdateProcedures](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/UpdateProcedures).
> - Bugs which represent **severe regressions** from the previous release of Ubuntu. This includes packages which are totally unusable, like
>     being uninstallable or crashing on startup.
> - Bugs which may, under realistic circumstances, directly cause a **loss of user data**
> - Bugs which do not fit under above categories, but (1) have an obviously safe patch and (2) affect an application rather than
>     critical infrastructure packages (like X.org or the kernel).
> - For Long Term Support releases we regularly want to enable new hardware. Such changes are appropriate provided that we can ensure to
>     not affect upgrades on existing hardware. For example, modaliases of
>     newly introduced drivers must not overlap with previously shipped
>     drivers.
> - New versions of commercial software in the Canonical partner archive.
> - **FTBFS**(Fails To Build From Source) can also be considered. Please note that in main the release process ensures that there are no
>     binaries which are not built from a current source. Usually those bugs
>     should only be SRUed in conjunction with another bug fix.
>
> For new upstream versions of packages which provide new features, but
>   don't fix critical bugs, a [backport](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) should be requested instead.

Answer (score 1):

Kernel will likely remain pretty static. Important updates will be made, but nothing fancy or new.

Security will always get updated.

Software will be hit or miss. Important bug fixes will make it, new features most likely won't, but it's up to the developer.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS

If your on a server stick to LTS, if your at home I recommend just updating to the latest version. Though you have to make the call. LTS versions are more tested, and stable, but only in the programmatic sense.

For example. Lets say you have tEdit (a fake text editor) in LTS, in current (non-lts) it gained the ability to copy and paste. This update also caused a bug where you can't tab.

LTS probably would not get that update as no one is really using tEdit, and it doesn't effect performance. Though some one out there may really like tEdit and may publish personal repositories that will let you install. This means current would get a tEdit that can copy and paste but not tab (till they fix the bug), and LTS would not be effected byt the tab bug, but would also not be able to copy and paste.

The basic idea is "better the devil you know" and it 100% true for business/server environments.

Now lets say libKeyboard (again fake) gets an update that allows you to not crash when pressing caps lock. That would end up in both LTS and Current because it effects everyone and is down right important.